# How to stop long-running cron process from being killed

Tags: cron, python

I have a long-running cron process, running a Python script, that seems to get randomly killed. In `dmesg` I see:

```
[230568.077358] init: cron main process (890) killed by TERM signal
[237517.974422] init: cron main process (19598) killed by TERM signal
```

How do I stop this from happening? I tried running the process via a lower nice value, e.g.

```
* * * * * nice -n 10 bash -c "/usr/local/myproject/myscript.py"
```

but it still gets killed. How do I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: Nothing is random in computing. Do you perhaps have a resource limit set somewhere on your system (maximum execution time? max CPU time?) that you are hitting?

Comment: @voretaq7, It's a stock Ubuntu 12.04 installation, so no, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is being killed as a secondary effect.  The log message indicates that cron itself is being killed.  When a process with child processes is killed, it sends a SIGHUP to its children, causing them to exit as well.  That's what's killing your python script.

If the log line you list line is immediately followed by a line that says `init: cron main process ended, respawning`, then you know that something outside of init/upstart killed it and it was automatically respawned.  If that message does not exist, then cron was killed by init/upstart, the same as if you ran "sudo restart cron" or "sudo stop cron".

So your new research project is figuring out what is either killing or shutting down cron.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your process is toooo long runnig and cron blocks on it.

Tyr runnig your process in background. To do this just add an "&" and the end.